# How to add all foreign key relations in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have these two models :

```
class Country(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Population = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Language = models.IntegerField()
    Total_persons= models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
```

In `Country` I have USA, CANADA, MEXICO, SPAIN, FRANCE......
In `Person` I have more than 1000 persons.

How can I make the `Total_persons` increase as the Total number of `Persons` increase in that country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making `Total_persons` a separate field, you can drop the field and simply get the number of `Person`s belonging to a `Country` instance `country` with:

```
country.person_set.count()
```

Or if you prefer a friendlier name, you can give the `Country` foreign key in `Person` a `related_name`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='persons', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

so that you can get the same count with:

```
country.persons.count()
```

Or if you'd still prefer to make `Total_persons` a separate field, you can override the `Person.save()` method to sync its country when a `Person` instance is created (when its `pk` is `None`), and override the `Person.delete()` method to sync when `Person` instance is deleted:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.pk:
            self.Country.Total_persons = self.Country.person_set.count()
            self.Country.save()
    def delete(self):
        country = self.Country
        super().delete()
        country.Total_persons = country.person_set.count()
        country.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your model field names should be lower case. 
See [Coding Style-Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) for more information. Also your population and language fields don't seem to have the right data type??

Another way to achieve what you need is by using model properties.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    population = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def total_people(self):
        return self.people.count()

class Person(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                related_name='people')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: You should use `.count()` instead of `len(self.countries)`, else queryset will be evaluated for count where only the a DB request can give the requierements.

Comment: @Zulu I have changed the answer to reflect that. Would be good if you could remove the downvote, as my answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to have the number of people in countries without a DB field:

With [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
qs = Country.objects.annotate(total_people=models.Count('person_set'))
for country in qs:
    print(country.total_people)
```

Else if you really want to have a DB field, you can use post/pre hooks.
There are:

- [Post save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save)

  ```
  @receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
  def increment_total_people(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      instance.Country.Total_persons += 1
      instance.Country.save()
  ```
- [Post delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-delete)

  ```
  @receiver(post_delete, sender=Person)
  def decrement_total_people(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      instance.Country.Total_persons -= 1
      instance.Country.save()
  ```

But you'll have to design things for all use cases when this number could change.